# Creating directory?

Tags: oracle, directory, oracle9i

When I create a directory using `sytem` user (`vin.txt` is my file)

```
create directory emp_dir1 
     AS "'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\vin.txt'";
```

it creates it.

When I do the same using user `Scott` it gives an error for path of file that

```
"Identifier is too long"
```

but when I put this file path in single quotes instead of double quotes for scott, it creates it.

What is the reason behind?

Comment: where do you create it ? using which software ? sqlplus ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using double-qoutes?

Strings in Oracle have single quotes, while double quotes can be used around column- and table-names.

---

I tried it using `Oracle 10.2` (don't have any `9g` around), and I can't reproduce this. It's never working, no matter what user I use.

When the string is as long as yours, I always get

> ORA-00972: identifier is too long

When I try a shorter path (`CREATE DIRECTORY emp_dir1 As "C:\vin.txt";`) I get

> ORA-01780: string literal required

Comment: I presumed it was a typo, otherwise it would have errored, run by SYSTEM or not

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things concern me about your question.

Firstly, regular users such as SCOTT should not be creating directories.  The CREATE ANY DIRECTORY is extremely powerful, because it confers read/write privileges on any OS directory which is accessible to the `oracle` account; this is a massive security hole.

Secondly, the directory path must be just the path, without a file.  We create files using UTL_FILE, Data Pump or whatever.  A call to `UTL_FILE.FOPEN()` will fail if the passed DIRECTORY is actually a path to a file not an OS directory.

I cannot explain why the same statement executed successfully by SYSTEM fails when executed by SCOTT.  I don't have 9i to hand, so I cannot test it.  Please cut'n'paste the whole SQL*Plus output so that we can see what happens.  As Peter has noted, your question appeared to contain a typo, so at the moment we cannot be certain that what you think is happening actually *is* what is happening.

Comment: +1, good point about security and about a `DIRECTORY` having to be, well, a directory.